# View Contextual Filter format for Block

Tags: views

I have created a View on my /blog/ page for displaying blog articles. For layout reasons this view is in a block.

This view has a contextual filter for Taxonomy tid on node and, since it is a block, it has a default value of Taxonomy Term ID from URL. When I enter tids in the preview box it works.

However, how do I format this in the url? /blog/1 /blog/term/1 and /blog?tid=1 all return 404 pages. How do I put the tid in the url?

Comment: Are you using 'page manager' with your Views. As this is where you can set which argument from the URL to send over.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly contextual filter works with **/blog/page/[contextual filter id]** e.g. **/blog/page/2**

By default its hard to pass the contextual filter id to a block, but you can do it this way

If you have url **blog/page/2** then you can set this as shown in the image(3rd argument is 2 that will  be passed to view block ), also add necessary relations accordingly.

Hope it will help you.

[image]